# Oracle COMPOUND TRIGGER with initialization section not working properly in Flyway

Tags: oracle11g, flyway

I would be happy getting support to following problem:

If I try to integrate a PL/SQL-Script with a COMPOUND Trigger and a initialization section, it will be cutted after the first ";" in the initialization section:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_COMPOUND_TRIGGER
    FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON COUNTRY
COMPOUND TRIGGER
--
-- Common or Initialization Section
--
    strProgPos          Varchar2(200) := 'START';
    STATUS_VALID        constant number := 1;

--
-- After Row Section
--
AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN

END AFTER EACH ROW;
--
-- After Statement Section
--
AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN

END AFTER STATEMENT;

END  MY_COMPOUND_TRIGGER;
/
```

==> This leads to following exception:
[ERROR] com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 9:     STATUS_VALID        constant number := 1
[ERROR] Caused by java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: Ungültige SQL-Anweisung

I use:

- flyway-maven-plugin:2.1.1
- Oracle 11gR2 11.2.0.3.0
- Java 1.6.0_21-b07
- Windows 7 64-Bit

This seams not a driver problem, anyway I tried following drivers:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>    
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
</dependency>
```

Would be happy about any hint or suggestion?

I also created a issue for that on flyway: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/487

Answer (score 0):

I studied flyway code and it looks like it does not count that trigger may have ; before declare or begin statement.

I suggested fix:
https://github.com/cipous/flyway/commit/c7cf111f666ef417337edf3ac2410f6688abaf1f

So hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: that fix was merged, so you can checkout and compile latest version or wait for release